# RailsのActionMailerで501 Recipient syntax errorが発生しメールが送信できません

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

唐突で大変、申し訳ありません。

現在、RailsでActionMailerを用いて問合せフォーム実装しているのですが、下記エラーが表示されメールを送信することができません。 
原因は何でしょうか？

エラー文 
Net::SMTPSyntaxError in InquiriesController#thanks

501 Recipient syntax error

コントローラ

```
def thanks 
 @inquiry = current_user.inquiries.build(confirm_params) 
 @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])

 @inquiry.blog_id = @blog.id

 if params[:back] 
    render :new 
 elsif @inquiry.save # DBに保存できたらメールを送信
```

@mail = InquiryMailer.sendmail_confirm(@inquiry,@blog).deliver_now 
     else 
        render :new 
     end

```
end
```

ブラウザでは、`@mail = InquiryMailer.sendmail_confirm(@inquiry,@blog).deliver_now`に問題があると表示されています。501エラーがどのようなものかも分からず困っています。 
何卒宜しくお願い致します。

## ・追記しました(現在の最新のソースコードになります)

## team_inquiries_controller.rb

class TeamInquiriesController < ApplicationController

def new
  @team_inquiry = current_user.team_inquiries.build
end

def confirm
    @team_inquiry = current_user.team_inquiries.build(confirm_params)

```
if @team_inquiry.valid?

else
  render action: 'new'
end
```

end

def thanks
    @team_inquiry = current_user.team_inquiries.build(confirm_params)
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])

```
@team_inquiry.blog_id = @blog.id

  if params[:back]
    render :new
  elsif @team_inquiry.save # DBに保存できたらメールを送信
    @mail = TeamInquiryMailer.sendmail_confirm(@team_inquiry,@blog).deliver_now
  else
    render :new
  end
```

end

private

def confirm_params
    params.require(:team_inquiry).permit(:content,:blog_id)
  end

end

#### ※上記、thanksアクション内の、.sendmail_confirm(@team_inquiry,@blog)の中身です。@mail =TeamInquiryMailer~の上で実行しました。

raise @team_inquiry.inspect
TeamInquiry id: 137, content: "今日はいい天気ですね！！", created_at: "2016-04-19 06:06:53", updated_at: "2016-04-19 06:06:53", user_id: 265, blog_id: 8

raise @blog.inspect
Blog id: 8, title: "こんにちは！！", content: "明日は宜しくお願いします！！", created_at: "2016-03-25 00:41:21", updated_at: "2016-03-25 00:41:21", user_id: 262, activity_area: "東京都", our_team_id: 5

## team_inquiry_mailer.rb

class TeamInquiryMailer < ApplicationMailer

#デフォルトのヘッダ情報
   default from: "info@ailes.com"   # 送信元アドレス

def sendmail_confirm(team_inquiry,blog)
    @team_inquiry = team_inquiry
    @blog = blog

```
mail to: blog.user.email, cc: ([@team_inquiry.blog.title, @team_inquiry.user.name, @team_inquiry.content]), subject: "投稿したブログに問い合わせがありました。"
```

end

end

## sendmail_confirm.html.erb

・投稿したブログのタイトル
%= @team_inquiry.blog.title %

・お名前
%= @team_inquiry.user.name %

・問合せ内容
%= simple_format(@team_inquiry.content) %

## team_inquiry.rb

class TeamInquiry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :blog
  validates :content, length: { in: 1..500 } #1000文字以下で入力
end

## blog.rb

class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :our_team
has_many :team_inquiries, dependent: :destroy
end

## routes.rb

resources :blogs do
    resources :comments

```
member do
  get 'team_inquiries' => 'team_inquiries#new'
  post 'team_inquiries/confirm' => 'team_inquiries#confirm'
  patch 'team_inquiries/thanks' => 'team_inquiries#thanks' #PATCHリクエストに対応 
  post 'team_inquiries/thanks' => 'team_inquiries#thanks' #送信完了ページ
end
```

end

## schema.rb

create_table "blogs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "activity_area"
    t.integer  "our_team_id"
  end

create_table "team_inquiries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "blog_id"
  end

現状は、team_inquiries_controller.rbのthanksアクション内の.deliver_nowをコメントアウトすれば、thanks.html.erbが表示され、DBには正常に保存されます。

Comment: `InquiryMailer`のコードも質問に追記してください

Comment: SMTPにおける501エラーは「パラメータ等の構文上のエラー(SyntaxError)」を表しています。`Recipient syntax error`とあるので、受信者(=送信先=`to`パラメタ)に構文上の誤りがあるのでしょう。`sendmail_confirm(@inquiry,@blog)`で変なデータを設定しているので、その後の`deliver_now`のところでエラーが検出されているのだと思います。`InquiryMailer`のコード(特に`sendmail_confirm`の部分)、その時の`@inquiry`, `@blog`のデータなどがわからないと、これ以上は何とも言えません。

Comment: お忙しい中、コメント頂き誠にありがとうございますm(_ _)m
ソースコード追記しました。

「 sendmail_confirm(@inquiry,@blog)‌​で変なデータを設定しているので、その後のdeliver_nowのところでエラーが検出されているのだと思います。InquiryMailerのコード(特にs‌​endmail_confirmの部分)、その時の@inquiry, @blogのデータなどがわからないと、これ以上は何とも言えません。 」 => 

raise .inspectを実行し、追記いたしました。

他、必要なファイルのソースコードがありましたら再度アップ致します。
ご確認の程、何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sendmail_confirm`メソッド内のこの部分が根本的におかしいですね。

```
mail to: blog.user.email, cc: ([@team_inquiry.blog.title, @team_inquiry.user.name, @team_inquiry.content]), subject: "投稿したブログに問い合わせがありました。"
```

`mail`メソッドの`cc`パラメータには(通常のメールアプリでCCに何を記入するか思い出してください)`to`と同様に有効なメールアドレスを記載しなければいけないのに、`([@team_inquiry.blog.title, @team_inquiry.user.name, @team_inquiry.content])`と言う、明らかにメールアドレスの形式とは異なる文字列(の配列)が渡されています。

取り敢えず、上の行から余分な`cc`を指定する部分を削ってみてください。

```
mail to: blog.user.email, subject: "投稿したブログに問い合わせがありました。"
```

これで動作確認をした上で、本当に`cc`に何かを指定する必要があったのか(あったのならその宛先)を確かめてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！

アドバイス頂いた通り、「mail to: blog.user.email, subject: "投稿したブログに問い合わせがありました。"」、に変更したところ、エラー文が下記に変わりました(SMTP 501→500)。

**エラー文**
Net::SMTPFatalError in TeamInquiriesController#thanks
550 Unauthenticated senders not allowed
@mail = TeamInquiryMailer.sendmail_confirm(@team_inquiry,@blog).deliver_now

**Parameters:**
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"xnDIgjTN6ZGxUnMCKON1crTIB8Zb2W6zfN93e8hSX7eXCTYHmpt33vGAde6ambCegw8sREUzhjIF83vfQQVXbg==",
 "team_inquiry"=>{"content"=>"こんばんはー！！"},
 "commit"=>"送信",
 "id"=>"8"}

Comment: ブラウザには、「@mail = TeamInquiryMailer.sendmail_confirm(@team_inquiry,@blog).deliver_now」がおかしいと表示されます。SMTPコマンドの500は、「文法に間違いがあるため、コマンドが理解できない。」だと思いますので、まだ@mail = ~ の部分がおかしいのでしょうか？

Comment: エラー文の引用部には「550 Unauthenticated senders not allowed」とありますが、500でしょうか?550でしょうか?550だとしたらローカルのメールサーバが必ず認証を必要としているのに、その設定がなされていない状態だと思われます。ActionMailer用の設定がメールサーバの設定とあっているか確認してみてください。

Comment: すみません、エラー文は「500ではなく、550 Unauthenticated senders not allowed」です。私の間違いです。メールサーバーはsendgridを使用しているのですが、再度usernameとpasswordを設定したところ、開発環境、本番環境共に、正常にメールを送信することができました。エラーの原因は、「cc: ([@team_inquiry.blog.title, @team_inquiry.user.name, @team_inquiry.content])」、のccの箇所の記述が原因でした。教えて頂いた通り、ccを削除し、「mail to: blog.user.email, subject: "投稿したブログに問い合わせがありました。"」に変更したところ、開発環境、本番環境、共にメールを送信することができました。

Comment: 本件については無事解決することができました。
本当に本当にありがとうございましたm(_ _)m